# break array into sub array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array, for example:

```
{ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12" }
```

I want to break it into sub array. When I do testing it, it displayed error:

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException at line: String[] strarray = splitted.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Code:

```
public static String[] splittedArray(String[] srcArray) {
        List<String[]> splitted = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        int lengthToSplit = 3;
        int arrayLength = srcArray.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i = i + lengthToSplit) {
            String[] destArray = new String[lengthToSplit];
            if (arrayLength < i + lengthToSplit) {
                lengthToSplit = arrayLength - i;
            }
            System.arraycopy(srcArray, i, destArray, 0, lengthToSplit);
            splitted.add(destArray);
        }
        String[] strarray = splitted.toArray(new String[0]);
        return strarray;
    }
```

Comment: `splitted` is a list of arrays.  I think you need to do something like `splitted.get(0)` or `splitted.toArray(new String[][])` - but I'm pretty sure you can't do that :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `java.lang.ArrayStoreException` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html):

```
Thrown to indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong type of object into an array of objects.
```

You are attempting to store a String[][] into a String[]. The fix is simply in the return type, and the type passed to the `toArray` method.

```
String[][] strarray = splitted.toArray(new String[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
String[] strarray = splitted.toArray(new String[0]);
```

to

```
String[][] split = new String[splitted.size()][lengthToSplit];
for (int index = 0; index < splitted.size(); index++) {
    split[index] = splitted.get(index);
}
```

You'll need to change your return type to be `String[][]`